# Any options to use left join in "from table1, table2 where table1.id = table2.id" construction?

Tags: performance, join, left-join, psql

I have two queries. One is like:

`with table1 as (...), table2 as (...) and so on 
select * from table1, table2, ... 
where table1.column1 = table2.column1 and table1.column1 = table3.column1 etc.`

It works well and quite fast (200-500ms).But the problem is null cells. If there is any null field — it doesn't take whole row.

And another query is like:

`with table1 as (...), table2 as (...) and so on 
select * from table1 
    left join table2 on table1.column = table2.column
    left join table3 on table1.column = table3.column
    etc`

It gives me the result I want, but too slow (3-5min).

Is there any kind of solution to make first query save null fields and give me all the data?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible. You can use COALESCE condition.

> The COALESCE function returns the first of its arguments that is not
>   null. Null is returned only if all arguments are null. It is often
>   used to substitute a default value for null values when data is
>   retrieved for display, for example: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-conditional.html

```
with table1 as (...), table2 as (...)
select COALESCE(column1,''), 
       COALESCE(column2,'')
from table1, table2, ... 
where table1.column1 = table2.column1 and table1.column1 = table3.column1

 column1 | column2
---------+--------
 1       | one
 2       | 
 3       | other
```

If the column is null then the column will be blank.